# TS Easy Print on specific driver

Tags: windows, windows-7, printing, windows-terminal-services, erp

Hey guys I have a weird one for you...

I have a user that has a Brother HL-5370 hooked up to her PC with USB and a few more that are on the network.  We have an ERP system where if any report is generated with a barcode on it we are unable to use the Terminal Services Easy Print type when we are RDP to the server which is Server 2008 R2.

When we generate a report and the barcodes are on it and we use an Easy Print option to print we get a thunking spooler error.  I tracked that back ot the server, which has the print server role, not having the drivers.  I installed the drivers for this model and multiple others and has been working fine.

Yesterday the user was printing then suddenly all of the HL-5370's are showing up Terminal Service Easy Print instead of the driver name.  I tried other printers and they show up just fine.  This model is the only one.  I have uninstalled and re-installed the drivers, ran windows updates, restarted the spooler, rebooted the server, everything I can find.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I fixed it.  Luckily I have another Terminal Server with the same setup but this one had a different driver version on it.  I took the ini file and copied it to the trouble server and installed the driver and now it is working fine.